# C# CRM 2013 SDK Type or namespace name Plugin could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sdk, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have installed on my machine the CRM 2013 SDK for VS 2012 w/o problems. Now when i try to create my first plugin i have an issue: Type or namespace name Plugin could not be found

All the references are included. What can be wrong?

[image]

Comment: Probably in the samples from the sdk there is a Plugin.cs file you should copy to your project.

Comment: Also check the version of the .Net framework that your project is targeting.

Answer (score 0):

My error was that i gave a name to my project with whitespaces...